# Mod Rewrite - multiple condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a certain sub-domain which requires an SSL connection for all pages on that subdomain.

This is my current `.htaccess` script:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

I have a single page on the subdomain which must not have SSL access (causes issues with accessing files on another server without a certificate).

My mod_rewrite knowledge is very limited. I've done a search but can't find what I need.

My question is, the page which **must not** have https is called 'tutorial.php'. Is there a way to redirect all pages **except** tutorial.php to https?

I guess in pseudo-code, the RewriteCond would be similar to:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 AND {WEB_PAGE}!='tutorial.php'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/tutorial\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^tutorial\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/tutorial.php [R,L]
```

Comment: That's worked perfectly @jonlin, thanks very much! I'll accept the answer (but have to wait 5 minutes). Thanks again :)